# Update multipe records of table with composite primary key from select

Tags: sql, oracle

My table has the following structure:

- 4 columns (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD)
- With the 3 columns (columnA, columnB, columnC) as the primary key.

How do I update multiple rows other than using a for-loop?

I'm looking for something like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET columnC = 'something' 
WHERE (columnA,columnB,columnC) IN (
    SELECT columnA,columnB,columnC 
    FROM table 
    WHERE columnD = 'somethingD'
);
```

Notice I'm trying to update a column that is part of primary key.**

Comment: Have you tried your code?  It should work.

Comment: For a very very strange reason it didn't work the first time I did it. But actually it is working right know, maybe I was missing something, thanks for taking the time for answer.

Comment: It will not work, if you try to update in a way that violates the Primary Key constraint. (Or unique or check constraints you may have on your columns, etc.) But otherwise it *should* work.

Comment: Your query should work, But it will be good if you can revisit your implementation with the business logic. Because Updating a primary key of a table in a production environment is not good. It could give you frequent constraint violation errors

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE <tablename>
SET    columnc = 'something'
WHERE  columnd = 'somethingD';
```

---

This query should work if you have same value in columnD for multiple rows of the table, and yes you can update columns which are part of composite primary key until your updated value does not violate the unique constraint of the composite primary key.